# Require Apex Classes

Tags: apex, package

Installing this package requires the following feature and its associated permissions: Apex Classes.

How will I install package containing apex classes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't install the package because your organization does not support Apex Code, and the package is not configured to be installed in orgs that do not support Apex Code. The solution is to talk to your Account Executive about upgrading.

Comment: I have dev Edition  Org with partner access . From this org I created my package. Now I want to test this on  some real org like Professional Edition (trial period) . How can I proceed ? Whats the best way to test real scenrarios in this case ?

Comment: thansk @sfdcfox for prompt reply .. help me with this new query please ..

Comment: @AshishGaonker You will have to have your app certified first, in that case, or wait until you can get a hold of DX. Once certified, then PE orgs can install your package, assuming there are no additional dependencies.

Comment: what do you mean by "wait until you can get a hold of DX" ?

Comment: @AshishGaonker Salesforce DX. The new Developer Experience. We're piloting it now, but it'll (hopefully) be Developer Preview soon. Unfortunately, we're a client, not an ISV, so it's not quite as useful as it would be for an ISV, but it's shaping up to be revolutionary.

Comment: Hey @sfdcfox Is it possible to test this in EE 's sandbox org?

Comment: @AshishGaonker Yes, your package can be installed in any EE org, including sandbox EE orgs.

Comment: No I mean without the review. just for doing testing. ?  Currently we get Installing this package requires the following feature and its associated permissions: Apex Classes . Cant find out way around this on sandbox on EE/PE. Currently its only installing on DE

Comment: @AshishGaonker Installing in EE should be okay; you'd have Apex Classes for EE even in a Sandbox. Make sure you're using an EE org.

Comment: Ya unfortunaltely I get this error while Isntallaing package :  "Installing this package requires the following feature and its associated permissions: Apex Classes" .   . Package url : https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04ti0000000tAfa